# In Xamarin can we have own name and location for google-services.json ? Can we change the content of file dynamically after application installed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to have my own name for google.services.json file and also some custom location inside my application.

And when we launch the application, I want to load the content of file from api. Is it possible to override the content of the file or not?

Comment: May I know why you would like to change the content? In general, the content in `Google-services. json` file is generated based on the properties previously configured for your app. If you arbitrarily change the content, your app probably won't work.

Comment: I will have the two apps, one for prod and one for development, on the environment base I wanted to change the content. let's consider default is prod. but to test the application i wanted to switch to test

Comment: In general, it is not recommended to modify the `Google-services. json` file directly. You can modify other properties of the APP to achieve your requirements.